# Disable ng-click from outside element on link inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click

I have a site using ui-router where I have a table and I have an ng-click on the cells, but have a link inside the cell. I need to disable the ng-click from the cell, when the link is clicked.

```
<div ng-click="click()" style="background: #d3d3d3">
  <a ui-sref="about">go to about page</a>
</div>
```

When I click this link, I want it to go to the about page, but not call the click function. Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/kE9CZYcYu1OPA9S0K3Jk?p=preview

This is a little different than my actual site, but this has the same behavior (div instead of table). I've tried adding `ng-click="$event.preventDefault()"` but that did not resolve it either.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"` on the anchor perhaps so that it does not bubble up to run the `click()` on its parent.

Comment: @PSL that worked. You're awesome! If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Timothy - @:charlietfl has updated his answer since, which you may accept..

Comment: @Timothy: Rather than adding an unnecessary ng-click event on your link, try to use $event.currentTarget and execute you event handler code. This don't require you to add ng-click on anchor tag. Because you have anchor tag in table column you will end up with lot of event handler for anchor tags. So I think performance wise this would be better with only required event handler on your table cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prevent propagation of event on the `<a>` tag bubbling to the div

```
<a ui-sref="about" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">go to about page</a>
```

Another way is to check target of click inside the click handler

```
<div ng-click="click($event)">
```

JS

```
$scope.click = function(e){
   if( e.target.tagName ==='A'){
       return; // skip click event handler
   }
    // rest of click code
}
```

Comment: just put up an alternative so you'll know how in the future

Answer (score 1):

You should try `$event.stopProgation()`

```
<div ng-click="click();" style="background: #d3d3d3">
  <a ui-sref="about" ng-click="$event.stopProgation()">go to about page</a>
</div>
```

Which will not propagate events to there parents.

Comment: I too think stopPropagation is the way to go, but should n't it be on the anchor so it does not bubble up to run click() on its parent ?

Comment: propagation means bubbling up the tree..not down, the event will start on the `<a>`...bubble up before the div sees it

Comment: right..but it will still occur on the div but no further up the tree